# Is it possible to grant trigger permissions on only one schema MySQL

Tags: mysql, permissions

I am an analyst that was recently granted a schema on MySQL that I could use for some business needs.

I was told by my DBA that the permissions associated with Triggers require global super user privileges. It's reasonable that I don't have global super user privileges, but would like to have those privileges for a schema that I have ownership on.

Is this something that is possible? If so, how do you do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend greatly on what version of mysql you are on. If you are on 5.1 or higher (specifically later than 5.1.6)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19815837/in-mysql-what-privileges-are-required-for-executing-a-trigger

> MySQL takes the DEFINER user into account when checking trigger privileges as follows:
>
> At CREATE TRIGGER time, the user who issues the statement must have the TRIGGER privilege. (SUPER prior to MySQL 5.1.6.)
>
> At trigger activation time, privileges are checked against the DEFINER user. This user must have these privileges:
>
> The TRIGGER privilege. (SUPER prior to MySQL 5.1.6.)
>
> The SELECT privilege for the subject table if references to table columns occur using OLD.col_name or NEW.col_name in the trigger body.
>
> The UPDATE privilege for the subject table if table columns are targets of SET NEW.col_name = value assignments in the trigger body.
>
> Whatever other privileges normally are required for the statements executed by the trigger.